# "Kiali secret is missing" but it's definitely there

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio, azure-aks, kiali

My Kiali installation returns 520 when logging in.

In my console is being printed:

```
W1105 08:23:28.238619       1 kiali.go:145] Kiali is missing a secret that contains both 'username' and 'passphrase'
E1105 08:23:34.142346       1 authentication.go:108] Credentials are missing. Create a secret. Please refer to the documentation for more details.
```

This is strange, because running

```
kubectl describe secret kiali -n istio-system
```

provides me with the following output:

```
Name:         kiali
Namespace:    istio-system
Labels:       app=kiali
              flux.weave.works/sync-gc-mark=sha256.ZNNGIdiNNcRZl-YCuc551EB3Edthk6kuz-PlDVn6U9k
Annotations:  flux.weave.works/sync-checksum: ae50afa268598e23696d4e980b1686829b3589e4

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
passphrase:  5 bytes
username:    6 bytes
```

restarting the pod does not solve the issue.

**Versions used**
Kiali: Version: v0.18.1, Commit: ef27faa

Istio: 1.1.2

Kubernetes flavour and version: Azure AKS

To Reproduce
Deploy Istio to your AKS cluster using the following resource:
https://github.com/timfpark/fabrikate-cloud-native

**Edit:**

It turns out updating to 1.1.5 is all that was necessary. 
Also the repo I was using isn't the official version. That can be found here:
https://github.com/microsoft/fabrikate-definitions/tree/master/definitions/fabrikate-cloud-native

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue, upgrade to istio 1.1.5 or higher. you can use my [example repo](https://dev.azure.com/4c74356b41/_git/fabrikate) with istio 1.2.0. that would fix it as well.

https://github.com/rootsongjc/cloud-native-sandbox/issues/2

Comment: Thanks! I actually found this repo while searching. I'll have a look!

Answer (score 0):

As you're ensuring that secret contains the data, then one possible reason cloud be that secret is not mounted properly.

Check whether you have mounted the secret or not:

```
$ kubectl describe deploy/<deployment-name> -n <namespace>
... ... ...
        volumeMounts:
        - name: kiali-secret
          mountPath: "/kiali-secret"
      volumes:
      - name: kiali-secret
        secret:
          secretName: kiali
          optional: true
... ... ...
```